# Git interactive stage - character/line-wise

Tags: git

When working with JavaScript files, depending on the existing code-base, it can be common to come across code like this:

```
if( i == 2 )
{
    var bIsSupposedToBeTrue = false; // the line I actually need to fix

    eval('badbadbad');
};
```

This code has several issues that I need to fix to pass eslint.
For example, the double equals, accounting for hoisting, bad use of semi-colons and the usage of eval.

This code **also** has a line of code that I want to fix for the task I am currently working on - right in the middle of the ugly code.

I want to be separate the eslint fixes from the actual fix that I originally intended to work on.

Another complicating factor is usually I want to fix the eslint errors as I work, not at the end after I have already committed the target work.

I could reset --mixed, and then git add -p, but interactive staging isn't as fine-grained as I need.

Any git advice on how to separate-out the eslint changes and the originally-intended change?
Imagine if this spanned multiple files.

Something like character-wise interactive staging?

I should also add that I only wish to accomplish this via the command-line (no gui tools).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do what you want with `add -p`, but for this kind of thing I use `git gui` which allows you to select lines of text with the mouse and stage them individually. For this kind of picking, it's a good approach.

*Git extensions* on Windows also has a good UI for this, and *SourceTree* on OSX also has this functionality.

**EDIT** I just re-read your question. The above is true for line-by-line staging. For intra-line staging, you'll have to edit the line and stage/commit, then edit again.

**EDIT 2** you can do this with `add -p`. Use the `e` command to edit the hunk manually.

Comment: add -p doesn't work for me because it stages hunks, and I need a more-finegrained (character-wise) way of interactively staging  http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Interactive-Staging

Comment: @Jonathan.Brink, yes I re-read your question a moment ago and updated my answer. As git tracks content at the line level, you'll have to do this with multiple edits unfortunately.

Comment: Great! Using "e" with add -p is what I was looking for